# Restsharp Exception The URI prefix is not recognized

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm getting an exception from RestSharp `The URI prefix is not recognized` and can't figure out why.

Parameters

`requestBody` is just a POCO

`domain` is `some.company.com` and

`_config.AddPersonEndpoint` is `api/person/add`

```
public PersonResponse AddPerson(PersonRequest requestBody, string domain)
{
    var client = new RestClient(domain);

    var request = new RestRequest(_config.AddPersonEndpoint, Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(requestBody);

    var response = client.Execute<PersonResponse>(request);

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
        throw response.ErrorException;

    if (response.ErrorMessage != null)
        throw new PortalConnectivityException(response.ErrorMessage);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Data.ErrorMessage))
        throw new PortalException(response.Data.ErrorMessage);

    return response.Data;

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your desire to help the community and make it easier for others to find an answer but please give a little more detail about how you get into the situation.  This should also make it easier for others to find your question.

Comment: Could you add an example of the parameters that were being passed in *in the question*?  Without example input to this function, it would have been impossible for somebody else to answer this question, and hence the value of the question is less because somebody stumbling upon it might not recognize it as the same problem as theirs.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure that you're including a URI Prefix like `http://` or `https://`. Just sending the url `some.company.com/api/person/add` and not `http://some.company.com/api/person/add` will cause this error

Comment: there are similar questions already on the SO, but they don't rank well at all in google, hoping that adding this question with restsharp specifically called out will make it easier to find for devs in the future.